# error when add event in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, windows, monodevelop, gtk#

when i double click on Clicked signals to add new Clicked event, it not automatic add code. it show error

[image: error monodevelop]

i use newest version of Monodevelop and Gtk# Toolkit and Window7 platform
how to fix it ??

Comment: It would help a lot if you pasted the entire stacktrace of the error in your post, this is a very nondescript problem.

Comment: here: http://pastebin.com/YgXKvFQJ

Answer (score 0):

Try to add it manually. 
Into constructor of your window class write:

```
yourElement.Clicked += new EventHandler(Method);
void Method(~)
{
//logic
}
```

Where *EventHandler* is a delegate type of *Clicked* event, and *Method* is a method, which have same with *EventHandler* signature.

Comment: when i manually add event handle code. it run normal. But I do not want to time it must be added manually like this. anyone can fix it ??

Comment: I think, that's a monodevelop bug and you must report.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug still present in MonoDevelop 3.0.1. Look below for the full stacktrace. Adding an even manually is like Arman Stepanyan described it.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.CodeGenerationService.GetSuitableInsertionPoint (IEnumerable`1 points, IUnresolvedTypeDefinition cls, IUnresolvedMember member) [0x0003e] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/CodeGenerationService.cs:335 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem.CodeGenerationService.AddNewMember (ITypeDefinition type, IUnresolvedTypeDefinition part, IUnresolvedMember newMember, Boolean implementExplicit) [0x00043] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/core/MonoDevelop.Ide/MonoDevelop.Ide.TypeSystem/CodeGenerationService.cs:91 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.CodeBinder.BindSignal (Stetic.Signal signal) [0x000de] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder/CodeBinder.cs:182 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.GuiBuilderView.OnSignalAdded (System.Object sender, Stetic.ComponentSignalEventArgs args) [0x00000] in /build/buildd/monodevelop-3.0.1/main/src/addins/MonoDevelop.GtkCore/MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder/GuiBuilderView.cs:316 
>     at Stetic.WidgetDesigner.OnSignalAdded (System.Object sender, Stetic.ComponentSignalEventArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Stetic.Project+c_*AnonStoreyD.<>m*_17 (System.Object , System.EventArgs ) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Stetic.GuiDispatch.InvokeSync (System.EventHandler h) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Stetic.Project.NotifySignalAdded (System.Object obj, System.String name, Stetic.Signal signal) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Stetic.Project:NotifySignalAdded (object,string,Stetic.Signal)
>     at Stetic.ProjectBackend.Stetic.IProject.NotifySignalAdded (Stetic.SignalEventArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Stetic.ObjectWrapper.OnSignalAdded (Stetic.SignalEventArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Stetic.SignalCollection.OnInsertComplete (Int32 index, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Collections.CollectionBase.System.Collections.IList.Add (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke (System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at GLib.Signal.ClosureInvokedCB (System.Object o, GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at GLib.SignalClosure.Invoke (GLib.ClosureInvokedArgs args) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at GLib.SignalClosure.MarshalCallback (IntPtr raw_closure, IntPtr return_val, UInt32 n_param_vals, IntPtr param_values, IntPtr invocation_hint, IntPtr marshal_data) [0x00000] in :0